# How to iterate over Div and extract individual check box values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am very new to JavaScript / JQuery...

Need to iterate over the following segment of code and either return an array or single value the e-mail addresses assigned to these labels (these are hardcoded as the check boxes values):

```
<div id="emailCheckListId" class="checkList">

    <ul id="emailCheckListId_ul">
        <li>
            <label for="root.module.emailCheckList_0" class="checkListLabel">
                <input type="checkbox"  
                 value="johndoe@aol.com" 
                 id="root.module.emailCheckList_0" 
                 name="root.module.emailCheckList"/>
                       John Doe
            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="root.module.emailCheckList_1" class="checkListLabel">
                <input type="checkbox"  
                 value="janedoe@aol.com"
                 id="root.module.emailCheckList_1"
                 name="root.module.emailCheckList"/> 
                       Jane Doe
            </label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Have written a JQuery event listener which does this:

```
$('#emailCheckListId_ul').click(function() {
    var divElement = document.getElementById(emailCheckListId);

    // How to iterate over each element and obtain something like this:
    //
    // [johndoe@aol.com,janedoe@aol.com]
});
```

Any help would be most appreciative...

Thank you for taking the time to read this!

Answer (score 1):

[`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) is perfect for this. You can map over the set of `li` elements and retrieve the contained data like so:

```
$('#emailCheckListId_ul').click(function() {
  var divElement = $('#' + emailCheckListId);

  var emails = $(this).find('li input').map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
  }); // => ['johndoe@aol.com', 'janedoe@aol.com']
});
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hans/WmjDH/).

Comment: Thank you so much Hans Engel! In addition to this, how can I set it up so that I know what e-mails are checked and once someone unchecks the "check" e-mail (by removing the check mark) what e-mails are unchecked?

Comment: Ah, I think that would require very different code. You could keep a global array `checkedEmails`, empty at start. Register a `.change()` event for every checkbox and, based on the new value (checked or unchecked), add or [remove](http://wolfram.kriesing.de/blog/index.php/2008/javascript-remove-element-from-array) that checkbox's corresponding email to the array. Whenever the array is changed, have the text box updated by the new set of emails.

Answer (score 1):

If you're after checkboxes only, you'll want to use this selector: `"input[type=checkbox]"`

Additionally, `.val()` is favorable to `.attr('value')`

```
$(function(){
    var x = $("#emailCheckListId").find("input[type=checkbox]").map(function(){
        return $(this).val();
    }).get();
    console.log(x);  //=> ['johndoe@aol.com', 'janedoe@aol.com']
});
```

Comment: Not sure why you both don't use `this.value`.

Comment: Thanks macek! I am only after the value of the e-mail when someone clicks on multiple check boxes (e.g. an array of emails checked). How can I set it up that I know what e-mails are checked and once someone unchecks the "check" e-mail (by removing the check mark) what e-mails are unchecked?

Answer (score 0):

Plain js:

```
function getValues(el) {
  var result = [];
  var inputs = el.getElementsByTagName('input');

  for (var i=0, iLen=inputs.length; i<iLen; i++) {

    // Maybe test the value here and only add the ones that
    // meet some validation criteriion (e.g. not empty)
    result[i] = inputs[i].value;
  }
  return result;  // returns an array
}
```

I would put the listener on the div (inline here but you can do it onload or DOM ready or whatever):

```
<div id="emailCheckListId" onclick="getValues(this);" ... >
```

Comment: Thank you very much RobG! I need the listener to happen when someone automatically checks on a bunch of different check boxes and when they uncheck them. So, basically, I need my function to return an array of emails unchecked and checked each time an individual checkbox is clicked on.

Comment: Thanks guys, what I really need it to do is check multiple checkboxes (as an end user) and each time the checkboxes are checked to move the e-mails to an input text field. But, what ever ones are unchecked, to immediately remove them from the input text field (while keeping the remaining checked ones in).

Comment: This doesn't work, I put an alert after result[i] = inputs[i].value, like this: alert(result[i]). When I clicked on one check box, it immediately alerted with "on" (where does this come from?) and then just gave me all the e-mail addressed present in the list (but were not checked).

Answer (score 0):

Got it working and it also populates / unpopulates the e-mail input text field. The trick was using a filter: input:checkbox:checked

```
// Event listener which picks individual contacts
// and populates input field.
$('#emailCheckListId_ul input:checkbox').change(function() {

    // Declare array
    var emails = [];

    // Iterate through each array and put email addresses into array
    $('#emailCheckListId_ul input:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
          emails.push($(this).val());
    });

    // Assign variable as To: text field by obtaining element's id.
    var textField = document.getElementById("root.form.email");

    // Add / Remove array from text field
    textField.value = emails;
});
```

Wouldn't have been able to have done it without the help of all you wonderful people! Thanks for the assistance!